# Проверка быстродействия python 3.12

Tags: python, производительность

Решил проверить прибавку производительности новой версии python.
Запустил код на 4х версиях python (3.7, 3.9, 3.11, 3.12)
Код:

```
import time
times = []


def check():
   strt = time.time()
   sum_: int = 0
   for x in range(1_000_000_000):
      sum_ += x
   times.append(time.time() — strt)


for x in range(10):
   check()

print(times, sum(times) / 10)
```

Python 3.7.0:   36.27 с

Python 3.9.0:   32.78 с

Python 3.11.0: 32.27 с

Python 3.12.0: 37.71 с

Не смог понять, почему простой цикл на новой более оптимальной версии выполняется медленнее, чем на 3.7?

Comment: кто ж так тестит....

Comment: Очень синтетический тест. Никто не заботится о быстроте суммирования последовательных целых чисел. https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html

Comment: Я понимаю, просто нашел это странным. Еще проверил на скриптах к задачам с codewars (функции с рекурсией, разные алгоритмы), 3.12 все также медленнее.